# pandas substraction by column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, array-broadcasting

I have one time series on a pandas dataframe that has a row with the month. I've called df1. Then I get the monthly mean by group_by, I've called df2 the resulting dataframe. Now I would like to subtract the monthly mean of each column without using a loop. This is, the row "month==1" in df2, needs to be subtracted from all the rows where "month"==1 in df1.

In numpy I would reshape the matrix, perform the operation (due to numpy broadcast) and reshape it again. But I don't know what is the pandatonic way to do it. Despite I have the feeling that should be a super easy approach.

Here is an example where I do it in a super inefficient way with a double for loop.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                   'value': [51, 16, 17, 25, 28, 37, 39, 73, 84, 56],
                    'value2': [551, 165, 175, 255, 258, 375, 359, 735, 854, 556]})


df2 = df1.groupby(["month"]).mean()
df2["month"] = [1,2,3,4]

for mon in range(1, 5):
    for val in ["value", "value2"]:
        mon_mean = float(df2.loc["month"] == mon, [val])
        df1.loc[df1["month"] == mon, [val]] = df1.loc[df1["month"] == mon, [val]].apply(lambda x: x- mon_mean)
```

Any clue or pandas function that you would use is more than welcome.

**EDIT**:

How would you do it, if instead of subtracting df2 to df1 it would be a third dataframe, namely df3 with more rows than df1. So extending the previous example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                    'value': [51, 16, 17, 25, 28, 37, 39, 73],
                    'value2': [551, 165, 175, 255, 258, 375, 359, 735, ]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                    'value': [43, 32, 54, 54, 54, 35, 76, 65, 35, 74],
                    'value2': [745, 346, 175, 889, 543, 876, 345, 876, 345, 987]})

df2 = df1.groupby(["month"]).mean()
df2["month"] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for mon in range(1, 5):
    for val in ["value", "value2"]:
        mon_mean = float(df2[df2["month"] == mon][val])
        print(mon_mean)
        df3.loc[df3["month"] == mon, [val]] = df3.loc[df3["month"] == mon, [val]].apply(lambda x: x - mon_mean)
print(df3)
month  value  value2
0      1    9.5   387.0
1      1   -1.5   -12.0
2      1   20.5  -183.0
3      2   33.0   674.0
4      2   33.0   328.0
5      3    2.5   559.5
6      3   43.5    28.5
7      3   32.5   559.5
8      4  -21.0  -202.0
9      4   18.0   440.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `DataFrame` filled by aggregate values, so possible subtract by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) only filtered columns in list `c`:

```
c = ["value", "value2"]
df1[c] = df1[c].sub(df1.groupby(["month"])[c].transform('mean'))
print (df1)
   month      value      value2
0      1  23.000000  254.000000
1      1 -12.000000 -132.000000
2      1 -11.000000 -122.000000
3      2  -1.500000   -1.500000
4      2   1.500000    1.500000
5      3 -12.666667 -114.666667
6      3 -10.666667 -130.666667
7      3  23.333333  245.333333
8      4  14.000000  149.000000
9      4 -14.000000 -149.000000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1.groupby(["month"])[c].transform('mean'))
       value      value2
0  28.000000  297.000000
1  28.000000  297.000000
2  28.000000  297.000000
3  26.500000  256.500000
4  26.500000  256.500000
5  49.666667  489.666667
6  49.666667  489.666667
7  49.666667  489.666667
8  70.000000  705.000000
9  70.000000  705.000000
```

EDIT: For subtract in another DataFrame is used `month` converted to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for match data by months:

```
c = ["value", "value2"]
df2 =  df1.groupby(["month"])[c].mean()

df3 = df3.set_index('month')[c].sub(df2).reset_index()
print (df3)
   month  value  value2
0      1    9.5   387.0
1      1   -1.5   -12.0
2      1   20.5  -183.0
3      2   33.0   674.0
4      2   33.0   328.0
5      3    2.5   559.5
6      3   43.5    28.5
7      3   32.5   559.5
8      4  -21.0  -202.0
9      4   18.0   440.0
```

Comment: I extend the question, because I realized that my example was not accurate enough.

Comment: @Xbel - I try run edit code and got `KeyError: 'month'` - is possible add expected output for test my new solution?

Comment: @jerzal Corrected and added an expected output.Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: Thanks to you. I sould use more often Pandas, and deep in all these functions. They are extremely useful.